# How do I index two arrays in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, database

```
db.hello.ensureIndex({"array1":1, "array2":1})
```

MongoDB does not allow that, because they say "it can get out of hand". However, I know that my arrays will never exceed length of 3. How can I hack MongoDB to allow indexing multiple arrays at once?

> When using a compound index, at most
>   one of indexed values in any document
>   can be an array. So if we have an
>   index on {a: 1, b: 1}, the following
>   documents are both fine:
>
> {a: [1, 2], b: 1} {a: 1, b: [1, 2]}
>   This document, however, will fail to
>   be inserted, with an error message
>   "cannot index parallel arrays":
>
> {a: [1, 2], b: [1, 2]} The problem
>   with indexing parallel arrays is that
>   each value in the cartesian product of
>   the compound keys would have to be
>   indexed, which can get out of hand
>   very quickly.

Comment: Are you sure you need the index on both arrays? If you have a high selectivity already on one of them, that may be good enough.

Comment: @Thilo ... the first array has about 100 elements usually. The 2nd array has about 2-3 elements. Do you think I need to index the 2nd array?

Comment: @TIMEX Don't index the 2nd array and see how it performs using the explain command.

Comment: @Joe what if I don't have any data right now (the database is just for testing).

Comment: How many distinct values are in the two fields? If filtering on just one of the indexes eliminates already 95% of the documents, that could be enough.

Comment: Additionally you could store an array of a_b instead of a and b as seperate arrays (e.g. [1_1, 1_2, 2_1, 2_2] instead of [1,2], [1,2])

Comment: @Joe, @Thilo, @Remon Thanks for all the comments. The first array is a list of facebook friends (about 200 average?).  The second array is the first and last names of people...['Jennifer','smith']. In other words, I want to look up people who are in my friends_list and and also match their name.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The short answer to your question is; you don't. The only option available to you is to store the every unique pair as a single array element. So rather than :

```
{a:[1,2], b:[8,9]}
```

you store

```
{ab:[[1,8], [1,9], [2,8], [2,9]]}
```

Obviously this has a few downsides so it really depends on your specific usecase whether or not this is an appropriate workaround. I do agree however that mongo shouldn't reject multiple array indexes just for idiot proofing. It's a good feature for small/low cardinality arrays.